# Vuejs - v-if e v-else encadeados

Tags: html, vue.js

Boa tarde pessoal,

Tenho o seguinte html:

```
<template>
    <div  v-if="!visibleForm" style="min-height: 793px;">
     // conteúdo ....
    </div>
    <div v-else-if="visibleForm">
        <fieldset v-if="textoTipo === 'Efg'">
            <form-validacao1 :params="param"></form-validacao1>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset v-if="textoTipo === 'Abc'">
            <form-validacao2  :params="param"></form-validacao2>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</template>
```

Em resumo eu preciso mostrar uma div de acordo com o parâmentro e após mostrar a segunda, mostrar os fieldsets de acordo com um parâmetro

Comment: Opa, o que está acontecendo quando você está fazendo dessa maneira?

Comment: Não traz nada...Se eu tiro os if´s do fieldset me traz normalmente

Comment: qual a versão do vue? v-else-if é suportado a partir da versão 2.1.0. Poste todo o codigo que envolve a funcionalidade assim da para testar. Edit agora que apareceu o seu comentário, não esta aparecendo os fieldsets pq os dois ifs devem estar dando false

Answer (score 0):

O `v-if` não suporta múltiplas condições, utilize o `v-show` como abaixo:

```js
<template>
    <div  v-if="!visibleForm" style="min-height: 793px;">
     // conteúdo ....
    </div>
    <div v-else-if="visibleForm">
        <fieldset v-show="textoTipo === 'Efg'">
            <form-validacao1 :params="param"></form-validacao1>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset v-show="textoTipo === 'Abc'">
            <form-validacao2  :params="param"></form-validacao2>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</template>
```